# How to fetch data from SQL Server based on logged in user email address in PorwerBI with single stored procedure taking email address as parameter

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

How to fetch data from SQL Server based on logged in user email address in PowerBI with single stored procedure accepting the email address for logged in user as a parameter?

Actually I want to use single data set and logged in user should see only his organization data with single data set and data should not be visible to other users

Comment: How frequently does your data change? Can you use an import model and row level security? Does your data fit in memory?

Comment: actually I want to use live connection for some reasons

Comment: so for live connection if you have some solution then let me know